# Why tmux is changing my screen brightness?

Tags: tmux

With an empty .bashrc and .tmux.conf file, when I execute:

```
tmux
```

My screen brightness gets reset to the default (on a Dell XPS running Ubuntu 14.04.1). Tmux version's is 1.8.

Interestingly, this also happens when I create a new pane, suggesting it's related to the execution of a new shell.

However, it does not happen when opening a new gnome-terminal.

How can I find out which shell tmux executes? It seems to be different enough from gnome-terminal's one that it can execute this brightness reset command.

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit in .profile:

```
xbacklight -set 10
```

Tmux is reading a file for new login shells whenever a new pane is created, because tmux sessions can in theory be joined by multiple ssh-based clients for example.

These configuration lines do the trick, avoiding reading .profile:

```
# Avoid spawning login shells and sourcing .profile 
# every time a new     window/pane is created
set -g default-shell $SHELL 
set -g default-command $SHELL
```